# Create UIView with four corner points?

Tags: objective-c, uiview

How can i create UIView with four corner.

```
0 = "NSPoint: {79.583483072916664, 54.148963562011716}";  // top left
1 = "NSPoint: {274.96375, 30.877176879882814}"; // top right
2 = "NSPoint: {306.15565104166666, 357.91370518493653}"; // bottom right
3 = "NSPoint: {77.101464843749994, 363.47374218750002}"; // bottom left
```

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: What will be output, Please share a screenshot of it.

Comment: https://github.com/phaugsoen/MyMaps/blob/master/MAImagePickerController-of-InstaPDF-master/instaoverlay/MAImagePickerController/MADrawRect.m  check if this is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your view is not a regular rectangle you need to first draw a path i.e. `BezierPath` and get a shape and imposing the shape on to the View. This view `myView` would behave like any other normal view

```
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];    
    UIBezierPath *linePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    [linePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(points[0].x, points[0].y)];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(points[1].x, points[1].y)];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(points[2].x, points[2].y)];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(points[3].x, points[3].y)];
    [linePath closePath];
    CAShapeLayer *shape = [[CAShapeLayer alloc]init];
    [shape setPath:linePath.CGPath];
    myView.layer.mask=shape;
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
   [self.view addSubview:myView];
```

The output ScreenShot is as given below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your 4 corner points do not make a rectangle - a UIView cannot be an arbitrary quadrilateral.

For drawing irregular shapes you should look at Apple's docs for using bezier paths: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html

So something like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    [[UIColor yellowColor] setFill];

    UIBezierPath *linePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    [linePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(points[0].x, points[0].y)];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(points[1].x, points[1].y)];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(points[2].x, points[2].y)];
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(points[3].x, points[3].y)];

    [linePath setLineWidth:LINE_WIDTH];
    [linePath closePath];
}
```

Comment: No i need to make UIVIew. I guess can be done by applying CATransform

Comment: @Mahavir with CATransform, you can only perform Scale (to edit size), Translate (edit x,y posotion), Rotate (edit display angle). to calculate these transform with array of Points as parameter is difficult task.  UIBazierPath is better option.

Comment: `UIView`s cannot be irregular shapes. You need to create a `UIView` (with a transparent background if required) large enough to hold the shape you are trying to draw, and then use a `UIBezierPath` to draw the shape as mentioned. Taking your four points, find the xMin, yMin, xMax and yMax. Your `CGRect` for the view will be (x=xMin, y=yMin, width=xMax-xMin, height=yMax-yMin). When specifying your shape's points, don't forget to remove the (xMin, yMin) offset.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is polygon shape and not rectangle. You can not assign polygon shape to view.  but if you want to display only part of view fall between these points, you can draw UIBezierPath path with these points on view and then apply blend to clip outer part. here is sample code.

```
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake( a.x, a.y)];
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(b.x, b.y)];
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(c.x, c.y)];
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake( d.x, d.y)];
    [aPath closePath];

    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = aPath.CGPath;
    [self.layer setMask:shapeLayer];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CALayer for corners, Below lines create a view with corners rounded by 8.

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] init];

myView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
myView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
```

Or you can create view with certain frame like

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
```

Comment: This is not the appropriate solution