# Fully customising a UINavigationBar for iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm working on a project where the designer came up with the following great idea:

[image]

A navigation bar with a height of 175 and a slanted edge. Now I didn't think this would be a problem, but it doesn't seem like I can actually edit the frame and/or mask of a `UINavigationBar` anymore... Normal stuff like editing the frame, or the bounds doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone have any experience with this? I believe it's an iOS 11/Xcode 9 specific problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer right now but can guide you how to start it off. You can have your normal navigation bar with that yellow background. 

Then you want to draw it using `BezierPath`s (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254545/create-uiview-with-four-corner-points) for an example right under the navigation bar with the same background colour. adjusting your 4 different points.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you couldn't implement the design with the UINavigationBar. You may have to hide the system navigation bar and add a custom view on the top of view controller.

BTW, this design is quite Android-style...

Comment: Ah f*ck... Well, I guess I could make it with normal views and stuffs, but wouldn't that mean that I'd have to do that for every view controller in my application?... Ggwp Apple...

Answer (score 0):

You can't customize native `navigationbar` like this!.

So, you have to do it with custom view.

If you want this kind of navigationbar in every viewcontroller then,

subclass `UIView` and set it's all the properties and frame in that class.

Then in your viewcontroller just instantiate that class and add that view(instance) in your main view at top!

Comment: How would you go about navigating to other view controllers then?

Comment: you can do `pushviewcontroller` and `popviewcontroller` on your navigation controller to go forward and back. You must have navigation controller in your hierarchy but with navigationbar hidden!